# Select() to read in sockets

Tags: c, linux, sockets, select, ipc

I have a client server client connection where the server reads the message sent by the client every 1 second but I do not want the server to keep on waiting for a message for too long. I tried using the select() function but the server continues waiting for some message to read. Could anyone tell me what I am doing wrong please?

```
fd_set master;
fd_set read_fds;
FD_ZERO(&master);
FD_ZERO(&read_fds);
FD_SET(sock, &master);

while (1) {
    bzero(message, 256);
    sleep(1);

    read_fds = master;
    if(select(sock+2, &read_fds, NULL, NULL, NULL) < 0)
        error("ERROR reading");

    //if there is any data to read from the socket
    else if(FD_ISSET(sock, &read_fds)){ 
        n = read(sock, buffer, 256);
        c = buffer[0];
        printf("1st char is %c",c);
    }//close else if statement

    else printf("Nothing was read");
}//close while loop
```

Comment: `read(sock, buffer, strlen(buffer));` is definitely wrong here because `buffer` is not yet filled. If ts's an array you can use `sizeof` instead

Comment: Thanks, I fixed that but now it becomes a blocking call (in the sense that it does keeps on waiting for a message)

Comment: Do you mean `select()` or `read()` ?

Comment: have you made sure the socket is unbuffered? also `stdout` is buffered so your `printf` won't do anything straight away.

Comment: read() reads perfectly, but the server waits for read() to return something. I want that the server only waits for a read to happen for some seconds.

Comment: Then you have to ad a timeout parameter to `select()` (last parameter). With `NULL` it waits infinitely. As far as I remember the question you have been given a link to in your previous question is a good example

Comment: Thanks! That solved the issue!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A few comments that are too long to fit in the comments...

The first parameter to `select` really only needs to be `sock+1`.

By passing `NULL` for the timeout, `select` will block indefinitely (so you might as well have just called `read`).

When `select` does tell you that `sock` is ready for reading, there may only be one byte present, even if the other end wrote more then that.  You will have to loop, reading the socket until you get the number of bytes you want.  You will have to decide if you want the timeout only while waiting for the first byte, or if you want to timeout in the middle (I.e. is the `select` inside or outside the loop).

Normally, when using `select`, you only want to block in `select`, and not in `read`, so the socket should be put in non-blocking mode, and you should be prepared for the `read` to fail with `EWOULDBLOCK`.

If you do time out, do you want to close the connection?  If you got half way through a message, you can't just throw away the half and keep going because you would now be expecting the next byte to be another start of message when it will now be a middle.

Comment: Linux even has a "feature" wherein a socket that select claims is readable, doesn't have even that *one* byte to be read (for example a bad checksum).